# Removing excess objects from a dynamically changing list of objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a small project in Unity to test out some new features, primarly the [new Input System](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem) and i have some trouble wrapping my head around lists. My goal with this project is to make a script that creates a small cursor for each player to use and move around with using their respective controllers.

Currently, i am creating and storing objects within a list during runtime whenever my computer detects a new Gamepad Controller. What i am having issues with is finding a method that removes excess objects that are not inside a list, i.e. when the list gets reduced in size which in this case is when a player disconnects their Gamepad Controller.

I have had similar issues in past projects whenever i had to add and remove items from a list while trying to destroy said items in the scene.

I have tried searching for such an answer on trying to achieve this effect on multiple websites (including this one) but with no prevail.

This is my current code that i am using at this moment to add players whenever a new device is added.

```cs
public GameObject cursorPrefab;
public int amountOfPlayers = 4;
List<GameObject> currentPlayers = new List<GameObject>();

private void DynamicADP(){
  if(Gamepad.all.Count > amountOfPlayers) return;
  for(int i = 0; i < Gamepad.all.Count; i++){
       if(currentPlayers[i] != null) continue;
       Cursor obj = Instantiate(cursorPrefab).GetComponent<Cursor>();
       obj.PlayerDevice = Gamepad.all[i];
       currentPlayer.Add(obj.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Edit: While Kevins solution didnt quite solve the problem, it did however help me broaden my perspective on the matter which finally lead into a solution for what i desire with this piece of code! So i will accept Kevin's answer for it! Thanks Kevin!

Here is what i added, its very simple.

```cs
private void DynamicADP(){

    //Previous logic from the code snipper above

    if(currentPlayers.Count > Gamepad.all.Count){
       Destroy(currentPlayers.Count[currentPlayers.Count - 1]);
       currentPlayers.RemoveAt(currentPlayers.Count - 1);
       //Whenever there is a difference in size on both lists, remove the last 
       //object from both in-scene and from currentPlayers list.
}
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't increment through a list from the beginning and remove items from the middle, because the list changes, if you start from the end and loop backwards it will work fine - been answered here many times...

Comment: Really? I have never come across this kind of solution. I never even thought of reversing the order. i will try it once i have some time. If it works (and im sure it would) then ill mark your answer c:

Comment: Ok, i have done some experimenting and i have found a very simple solution that was inspired by your comment. While your solution didnt solve the problem at all, it did offer me a new perspective to think around the problem which helped me solve it in the first place, so ill mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the loop to remove items from a list.

```
private void DynamicADP(){
   if(Gamepad.all.Count > amountOfPlayers) return;
   for(int i = Gamepad.all.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--){
       if (somelogic) Gamepad.all.RemoveAt(i); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List is not a UnityEngine class, if you seek for List methods on unity, you'll never find. But in Microsft API documentation you can.

I never used list in Unity, but I think this way should work:

```
currentPlayers.RemoveAt(removed_controller_index);
```

See more of Lists on Microsft docs:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2